# What is the best approach to Protect webgl assets

Tags: three.js, webgl

We are using WEBGL to render OBJ models . What is the best approach to protect these assets.
or at least make it difficult for someone to pull out the obj mesh . source.
There has been few threads discussing this issue but most of them confined to rudimentary ways like disabling right click on browser etc.

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2):

The "best" approach is to write your own file format. The user aiming to read your files will then have to find the loading code in your minified code.

Comment: The question though is it worth the trouble? Many people have reverse engineered the 3d file formats of famous 3D games with binary assets. With things like PIX and other GPU tools it's easy to pull out the data AFTER the data has been decrypted and is about to be uploaded to the GPU. So yes, you could make your own format, the question is is it worth your time. If it's for the sole purpose of trying to protect your assets probably not.

Comment: @gman ...or you could run it with custom three.js that will serialize geometry and / or textures.

Comment: @gmain yep, that's a different question. the only benefit I see is that somehow you make people feel a bit more bad for ripping your assets :)

Answer (score 1):

What's the best approach on any other platform? I can stick the CD or DVD from any console game in my PC and read the files directly off the disc. I can look at any files installed on my PC games. I can back up the apps on my iOS or Android devices and read those files on my PC. What do you expect to be different in WebGL?